# keen-slider react js extra dots showing issue

Tags: reactjs, slider, next.js, carousel, keen-io

There is bug which I can't solve there is a bug in keen-slider react js, when the no more item to slide but dots is appearing

there is code sandbox code
https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-fog-ekwqd?file=/src/App.js

Comment: That's not a bug. There are 6 dots because you are rendering a dot for each item on the slider.

Comment: @juliomalves thanks for you comment
but how can I resolve this issue

Comment: @shajadsheikh please have a look at my comment i believe it will fi your issue

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no apparent solution provided by the library, a workaround is set less dots than maximum.

In your case, put "-2" when getting the length of slides:

```
{slider && (
    <div className="dots">
      {[...Array(slider.details().size - 2).keys()].map((idx) => {
        return (
          <button
            key={idx}
            onClick={() => {
              slider.moveToSlideRelative(idx)
            }}
            className={"dot" + (currentSlide === idx ? " active" : "")}
          />
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )}
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone else facing the same issuse using keen slider I believe you are using **BREAKPOINTS** and that is the issue because in the example of using dots there is no break points but to take into account calc of breakpoint use the below

> const perSlideConf = instanceRef.current?.options?.slides?.perView - 1 ?? 0;

```
  const [ref, instanceRef] = useKeenSlider<HTMLDivElement>({
    mode: "free",
    rtl: lng === "ar",
    breakpoints: {
      "(min-width: 700px)": {
        slides: { perView: 3, spacing: 5 },
      },
      "(min-width: 1400px)": {
        slides: { perView: 4, spacing: 5 },
      },
    },
    slides: {
      perView: 1,
      spacing: 0,
    },
    slideChanged(slider) {
      setCurrentSlide(slider.track.details.rel);
    },
    created() {
      !!salonsData && setLoaded(true);
    },
  });



const perSlideConf = instanceRef.current?.options?.slides?.perView - 1 ?? 0;
```

then

```
                {[
                  ...Array(
                    instanceRef.current.track.details.slides.length - perSlideConf,
                  ).keys(),
                ].map(idx => {
                  return (
                    <button
                      key={idx}
                      onClick={() => {
                        instanceRef.current?.moveToIdx(idx);
                      }}
                      className={cn(
                        "border-none w-[10px] h-[10px] bg-gray-300 rounded-full mx-[5px] p-[5px] cursor-pointer ",
                        currentSlide === idx ? "bg-[#6E4B87]" : "",
                      )}
                    ></button>
                  );
                })}
```